# regular expression to validate URL not working correctly in PHP

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am using a regular expression to validate URL. This expression works very well in JavaScript, But in PHP it gives me this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Filename: home/auth.php

Line Number: 1596
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Filename: home/auth.php

Line Number: 1601
```

This is my expression

```
$pattern ="/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*(\.){1}((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$/";
```

This is the php function

```
public function valid_url($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);

    if(!$data)
    {
        return TRUE;            
    }

    $pattern ="/^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*(\.){1}((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$/";
    $valid = preg_match($pattern,$data);

    if(!$valid)
    {
        $data = "http://".$data;
        $valid = preg_match($pattern,$data);
    }

    if(!$valid)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_url', 'Please enter a valid URL.');
        return FALSE;           
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }       
}
```

I am not very good at regular expressions so I could not figure out the issue, please help me correct the regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Wow, that is a big expression**. I found several faults in it, and I shall hopefully explain them to you. Let's break it apart:

```
$pattern ="/
```

Here was your first mistake. As a forward slash is used in multiple sections of a url, you should use a different delimiter. I would suggest a tilde `~`, as this is not used in a url very often. This would mean you don't have to keep escaping the forward slash every where with `\/`.

```
^(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+
```

This character class contains the next error. Within a character class, a dot just means a dot. There is no need to escape it. Furthermore, with placing the dash at the end, it also does not need escaping as it cannot possibly mean a range. The character class can be shortened to become `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+`.

```
(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+
```

Here we have the next error, `&amp;` within the character class. This will match an & or an a or an m or a ;, not just an &. You don't need to convert it to the html code as doing so will mean to match any of the characters that the code contains. And using the previous knowledge, you don't need to escape the dot, or the dash if it is at the end. You also don't need to escape the dollar sign, as in a character class it just means a dollar. Remember, within a character class, all meta characters are just standard characters except the caret `^`, the backslash `\`, the closing square bracket `]`, the dash `-` (but this can be left if it's at the end), and whatever you choose as your delimiter, e.g. tilde `~`. This character class can then become, `[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+`.

```
)*@)*(\.){1}
```

Part of this might be an error, it might not be. Basically, is there any need to capture the dot here? If there is not a need to capture it, leave the brackets alone. However, there is a definite error in the repetition. `{1}` is completely and utterly superfluous. Everything in there has to be repeated at least once. This is just making the code messy. The above can shortened into, `)*@)*\.`.

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}
```

Again, the `{1}` is not needed. Remove it, `((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]`.

```
[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

And again twice, this becomes `[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]`.
You keep doing this, the next block of code you have can be shortened:

```
|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])
```

Into

```
|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])
```

It's not amazingly better, but every little helps. Next:

```
|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+
```

The two character classes can be optimized, `|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`.

```
\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2})
```

This is very restrictive, but I assume you have it like this for a reason so I'll leave it.

```
)(\:[0-9]+)*(/
```

**And here is the cause of your error.** You did not escape the forward slash. However, I am going to leave it as using a different delimiter would avoid this and also tidy up your pattern.

```
($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$/";
```

That character class can be greatly shortened now knowing that we don't need to escape everything within them. It can become, `($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/";`.

**Using everything we now know your pattern can be made much prettier and easier to handle.**

It can become instead:

```
$pattern = "~^(http|https|ftp)://www\.([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=\~_-]+))*$~";
```

Now that you have a smaller expression, finding faults and more customization should be a little easier.

**Just a quick note**
I keep noticing that you have used the following syntax at the beginning of some groupings, `(\:`. I have removed the backslash as it is not needed for a colon. However, were you trying to make it so the group was not captured? If so, the syntax for that is, `(?:`.

Edit:: **You can also optimize the pattern further by utilizing character classes**

\d = [0-9]
\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Adding i to the end of the last pattern delimiter turns case insensitivity on too. Which means, instead of writing `[a-zA-Z]` you can just write `[a-z]` instead.

Also, the `http|https` can just become `https?`

So you pattern could be shortened further too:

```
$pattern = "~^(https?|ftp)://www\.([a-z\d.-]+(:[a-z\d.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d)|([a-z\d-]+\.)+(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-z]{2}))(:\d+)*(/($|[\w.,?'\\+&%$#=\~-]+))*$~i";
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , but it gives an error again . A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-'

Filename: home/auth.php

Line Number: 1598

Comment: Ah! My mistake, I didn't notice the tilde `~` in the character class at the end. It must be escaped. I have edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '\'  :( :( :(

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya. I feel a little foolish now. I placed the backslash in the wrong place! I placed it after the tilde by mistake when it should be before it. Move it to just before the tilde and that error shall disappear. For future reference, the error you are seeing means that an unknown character is appearing after the closing delimiter. To fix this, look for any misplacement's of the closing delimiter and escape them. (I have also updated my answer).

Comment: thank you very very much for the help , i am testing this now

Comment: mm now the error is gone again , but valid url's such as www.test.lk is returnnig false :(

Comment: If I was you I would throw away this pattern, and create a new one. It is ugly and restrictive. However, after some testing, to fix the current problem you need to remove the required dot just before the number section. `*@)*\.((` <- This bit. I have updated my answer to include the fix.

Comment: Glad to have helped! By the way, I just changed `([a-z\d-]+\.)*[a-z\d-]+` into `([a-z\d-]+\.)+` to make it less restrictive. I.e. More tdl's such as the .lk you mentioned will pass through with this. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I see one error:

`[0-9]+)*(/($`

to

`[0-9]+)*(\/($`

or to

`[0-9]+)*(($`

if the `/` is supposed to be an ender, which it's not supposed to be.

But seriously, is there no other way you can achieve this? This string is really hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: tank you very much , i am checking this

Comment: hmm  by doing that, the error is gone , but a valid url like www.google.com is validated as invalid :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use standard php function filter_var?

http://lv.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php

Comment: it has some custom validations rules . so i have to write it my own